# Why plotly fails to install using R-Studio but not in R?

Tags: r, package, plotly

OS: Ubuntu 17.1

I have tried to install plotly on R studio using `install.packages("plotly")`

It failed with the following log:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/company/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘hexbin’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘data.table’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/htmlwidgets_1.0.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/htmlwidgets_1.0.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/htmlwidgets_1.0.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘htmlwidgets’ failed
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/hexbin_1.27.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 491560 bytes (480 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 480 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/crosstalk_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 563474 bytes (550 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 550 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/data.table_1.10.4-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3071833 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/plotly_4.7.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1034951 bytes (1010 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1010 KB

Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hexbin’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘crosstalk’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTFlAaE/downloaded_packages’
```

For some reason it can't allocate memory but in R it succeeds?

What is wrong here? Please advise why can't I install it straight forward?

Comment: have you seen this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320594/how-to-install-r-plotly-in-debian

Comment: What do you mean by "in R it succeeds"? all the commands you enter in RStudio are executed by R!

Comment: I mean if I go to the terminal and run the same command, it works, but in R-Studio it fails because of memory...

Comment: @MarcoSandri please post as an answer.

Comment: OK, done. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the development version of `plotly` (on GitHub) via devtools:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```